# Binding to static field after deserializing data from an xml file - Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xml, binding, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am getting data from an XML file into a class called ExerciseTable using the "INotifyPropertyChanged". And I want to bind my data to a static TextBlock **without using any ListView or GridView ItemsSource.**

This is my class:

```
public class ExerciseTable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int questionsNum;
    bool feedback;
    bool randomAnswers;

    public int QuestionsNum
    {
        get { return questionsNum; }
        set 
        { 
            questionsNum = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("QuestionsNum");
        }
    }

    public bool Feedback
    {
        get { return feedback; }
        set 
        { 
            feedback = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Feedback");
        }
    }

    public bool RandomAnswers
    {
        get { return randomAnswers; }
        set 
        { 
            randomAnswers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("RandomAnswers");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

}

This is how I'm deserializing my XML file:

```
string XMLPathEx = System.IO.Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets/TableOfExercises.xml");
        XDocument loadedEx = XDocument.Load(XMLPathEx);
        //retrieving data from xml using LINQ     

        var exercise = from query in loadedEx.Descendants("exercise")
                       select new ExerciseTable
                       {
                            QuestionsNum = int.Parse(query.Element("settings").Attribute("qNum").Value),
                            Feedback = System.Convert.ToBoolean(query.Element("settings").Attribute("feedback").Value),
                            RandomAnswers = System.Convert.ToBoolean(query.Element("settings").Attribute("randomAnswers").Value)
                        };
```

And this is how I am binding to my TextBlock:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="NumberQuestion"  Text="{Binding ExerciseTable.QuestionsNum}"/>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you want to bind textblock to QuestionsNum, Feedback and RandomAnswers  properties simultaneously? And display them together?

Comment: No just QuestionsNum. And the binding is not working, nothing is displayed...

Comment: Do you set datacontext for textblock or any of its parents, including window?

Comment: No, how do you do that?

Comment: write `NumberQuestion.DataContext = exercise;` right after you deserialize;
And change you binding to `QuestionsNum` instead of `ExerciseTable.QuestionsNum`

Comment: Tried it, didn't work... should I call onPropertyChanged event somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The real question is going to be how you set the data context of the textblock. The reason you say "without using any listview" makes it clear to me that you are not 100% sure how you can set the datacontext without a repeater control like listview. Allow me to show you four ways.

1. Instantiating it in XAML

With this code:

> None

With this XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionsNum}">
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <models:ExerciseTable />
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>
```

2. Accessing it in XAML

With this code:

```
public class Locator {
    public ExcersizeTable CurrentTable {
        get {
            return new ExcersizeTable();
        }
    }
}
```

With this XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionsNum}">
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="CurrentTable">
            <Binding.Source>
                <models:Locator />
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>
```

3. Setting datacontext in code-behind

With this code:

```
public class MainPage: Page {
    public MainPage() { 
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }
    public void MainPage_Loaded() {
        MyTextBlock.DataContext = new ExcercizeTable();
    }
}
```

With this XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding QuestionsNum}" />
```

4. Setting text in code-behind

With this code:

```
public class MainPage: Page {
    public MainPage() { 
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }
    public void MainPage_Loaded() {
        MyTextBlock.Text = new ExcercizeTable().Text;
    }
}
```

With this XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" />
```

Each of those approaches is the right way to do it, depending on the details of your project. Most developers use #4 because they do not understand data binding. Typically, I use a higher-level datacontext, something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="CurrentTable">
            <Binding.Source>
                <models:Locator />
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionsNum}" />
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="Feedback:" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Feedback}" />
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Note how this approach allows you to bind to two properties while setting the datacontext only one time. This is because datacontext is a special type of property in XAML called a dependency property. One neat feature of this particular dependency property is that its values flows down through the XAML tree to every child element that doesn't explicitly set their own datacontext.

This allows you to set the datacontext property of an element very high in the XAML tree and reuse it in child elements without having to re-declare it.

How does a XAML repeater like listview do it? The exact same, just under the covers. As it repeats itself for each record in the list, it create a new child XAML tree and sets the datacontext to the individual element it is currently processing. Then your data binding works.

Setting the datacontext on your own is a fine way to build interfaces in XAML. That being said, all my samples set the datacontext to the model. This works, but is not typically the suggested approach. Most developers wrap their model(s) in a containing class we call a view-model. The view-model is what most developers set their datacontext value to.

> This is not the right place to teach MVVM, but I think you should research it. http://bing.com works just fine and there are many blogs and videos out there teaching MVVM. It's a very simple design pattern and ideally suited for XAML applications.

I hope this answers your question.

Best of luck!